# Why isn't my bot responding to commands sent from another bot account in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to write two discord bot by using discord.py, and the first one will use the command from the second bot automatically. However,the second bot did not response to the commands from the first bot. These are my code of the second bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = '.'
intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intent, activity=discord.Game(' .help'))

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("ah")
```

When I just send a message ".test" in discrod server, the bot will print "ah" in terminal. However, when I use a bot account to send the ".test" , then there nothing will happen, I think that is because the bot ignored the command message from bot account, so how do I turn off this setting?

PS: When I use "on_message" event, the bot can recieve the message from bot account, so it may just ignored the command message but not all the message.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by how discord.py is written, they have somewhere in the libary code a check if the message is from a bot account and if it is the commands.ext Command is not triggered.

If you want to change this you need to modify the file where this is set...

But an easier solution is just to modify the message and change the bot status in it before it is further processed. this can be done in an on_message event in the main file

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    m1 = message
    m1.author.bot = False
    await process_commands(m1)
```

but this has one massive drawback, you cannot check in any command if the author is a bot my simply using author.bot

the best solution is just to make the commands you want to be able to be triggered from an bot through something like this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("my_command"):
        my_command = bot.get_command("my_command")
        ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
        await my_command.invoke(ctx)
    await process_commands(message)
```